# Changing click into row action in AG-Grid

Tags: ag-grid

The default behaviour of AG-Grid when clicking a row is to make it a selection. I'm wondering if it's possible to have this selection mode enabled but only make it include the row when a user actually clicks the checkbox and not the *whole row*.

The reason for this is that I'd like to reserve clicking anywhere on the row (except the checkbox) should be reserved for showing details about the row. Selecting the checkbox should be the only way to include it as a selected item.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you are looking for this [suppressRowClickSelection](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/grid-options/#reference-selection-suppressRowClickSelection)

Answer (score 0):

**Yes, you can do that in ag-grid.**

[image]

> Refer to the official documentation page [here.](https://www.ag-grid.com/angular-data-grid/row-selection/#example-displaying-disabled-checkboxes)
>
> Refer the working sample [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/wr7jw5?file=/app/app.component.ts).

app.component.ts :

```
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import {
  ColDef,
  FirstDataRenderedEvent,
  GridReadyEvent,
  IRowNode,
  IsRowSelectable,
} from 'ag-grid-community';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import 'ag-grid-enterprise';
import { IOlympicData } from './interfaces';

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<ag-grid-angular
    style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
    class="ag-theme-alpine"
    [columnDefs]="columnDefs"
    [defaultColDef]="defaultColDef"
    [rowSelection]="rowSelection"
    [suppressRowClickSelection]="true"
    [isRowSelectable]="isRowSelectable"
    [rowData]="rowData"
    (firstDataRendered)="onFirstDataRendered($event)"
    (gridReady)="onGridReady($event)"
  ></ag-grid-angular>`,
})
export class AppComponent {
  public columnDefs: ColDef[] = [
    {
      field: 'athlete',
      headerCheckboxSelection: true,
      checkboxSelection: true,
      showDisabledCheckboxes: true,
    },
    { field: 'sport' },
    { field: 'year', maxWidth: 120 },
  ];
  public defaultColDef: ColDef = {
    flex: 1,
    minWidth: 100,
  };
  public rowSelection: 'single' | 'multiple' = 'multiple';
  public isRowSelectable: IsRowSelectable = (
    params: IRowNode<IOlympicData>
  ) => {
    return !!params.data && params.data.year === 2012;
  };
  public rowData!: IOlympicData[];

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  onFirstDataRendered(params: FirstDataRenderedEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    const nodesToSelect: IRowNode[] = [];
    params.api.forEachNode((node: IRowNode) => {
      if (node.data && node.data.year === 2012) {
        nodesToSelect.push(node);
      }
    });
    params.api.setNodesSelected({ nodes: nodesToSelect, newValue: true });
  }

  onGridReady(params: GridReadyEvent<IOlympicData>) {
    this.http
      .get<IOlympicData[]>(
        'https://www.ag-grid.com/example-assets/small-olympic-winners.json'
      )
      .subscribe((data) => (this.rowData = data));
  }
}
```